# Replace underscores on typing input in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, user-interface, backbone.js, frontend, web-frontend

I have a text field with little dashes/underscores as shown in the image. How do I use JavaScript/backbone.js to make these dashes to be replaced by the input number upon typing?
As I type, I want the underscore to be replaced with the number I type. How do I achieve this?

Thanks in advance

[input invoice field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dXFgk.jpg)

Comment: What have you tried?  What happened when you tried it? Please post some code: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I tried event handling by adding default value as underscore and then while typing I triggered an event to replace the underscore with the number.

Comment: I'm new to JavaScript so I'm not very sure I'm doing it the right way.

Comment: Hey, you can post the code using built in editor or format it using "```" and ask why it isn't working :)